# Ruby - Loop through an array , Remove end element of that array and append it to another array

Tags: arrays, ruby, insert, element

I am attempting the following coding challenge.

Write a program to loop through the array named `food` and remove the end element of that array, and append it to the array named `drink`. The initial values of these arrays are:

```
food = ["Tempura", "Prawn", "Squid", "Fish", "Chips"]
drink = ["Kombucha", "Coconut Mango", "Allberry", "Yogurt Rice", "Milk bubble tea"]
```

I know how to get the last element from the first array and append it to the second array.

```
print drink << food.slice(-1)
```

I struggle with finding the loop so that I can get the following out.

```
food_&_drink = ["Kombucha", "Coconut Mango", "Allberry", "Yogurt Rice", "Milk bubble tea", "Chips", "Fish", "Squid", "Prawn", "Tempura"]
```

How to match element 1 from the food array to element 4 in the drink array. With the method that I know, I am not getting the output the want:

```
print food.flatten.zip(drink)
```

Comment: @Arend May I ask you? I get the notification that you have edited this question. I am still relatively new to stackoverflow. Is my formatting not correct when I first posted this question? What did you edit? I want to learn so that I format properly for future posts. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, I've quickly editted out the ["Thanks in advance"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts), and made the post a bit less verbose. You can see the edits I made by clicking "Edited xx time ago" above my name

Comment: Thanks Arend! I am a first year CS student, just started my first semester. I will take notes of your edit and will make it less verbose in future posts! :)

Comment: Great! Be sure to check out the wonderful [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on the asking / answering section, it contains tons of great advice on how to phrase questions. If you're a CS student I would almost consider it life lessons in there :)

Comment: Thanks Arend for telling me about this help center! I will check it out. :)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest/clearest solution to reach your desired output (nondestructively):

```
drink + food.reverse
```

The solution matching your wording:

```
until food.empty?
  drink << food.pop
end
```

or even

```
drink << food.pop until food.empty?
```

Comment: Thanks @Amadan !! I find this code very elegant  `drink << food.pop until food.empty?. Thanks again.

Comment: Personally, me too — but there's people who intensely dislike statement modifiers.

Comment: Hi Amadan, May I ask you a question? When I print this code `drink << food.pop until food.empty?`, I get the following output. Is the any way I can hide or print out only the last line? Thanks! `["Tony", "Rhonda", "Charlie"]
["Tony", "Rhonda", "Charlie", "Bob"]
["Tony", "Rhonda", "Charlie", "Bob", "Fred"]
["Tony", "Rhonda", "Charlie", "Bob", "Fred", "Tommy"]`

Comment: That line should not print anything. I don't know where that is coming from, but it's not from that line.

Comment: Thanks! I have closed VS Code and tried it again, but still printing all each line. I will try it again after I close everything and restart my computer.